# When you drop or truncate tables in SQL Server do old data pages get overwritten with new data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When you drop tables, does the empty space get automatically reused, or do you need to do some sort of maintenance to allow that space to get reused?

Consider a situation where you drop and recreate a large lookup table routinely. For instance, every day. Is this going to use more and more space until you perform some maintenance like shrinking the data file, or something like that? Or will the old space get overwritten with new data as if it were a hard drive?

SQL 2014 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177570.aspx) first:

> `TRUNCATE TABLE` removes the data by deallocating the data pages used to store the table data and records only the page deallocations in the transaction log.

So it deallocates the pages and make them available for reuse.